# Hiding brackets after a definition

Tags: brackets, amsthm, examples, newtheorem

I use amsthm package to define the environment as

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright,notitlepage]{book}
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{amstext}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{theorem}    
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{multirow}           
\usepackage{xspace}             
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{latexsym}               
\usepackage{setspace}           
\usepackage{algorithm}              
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{makeidx}                
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{standalone}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
\usepackage{vmargin}                
\usepackage{float}        
\usepackage{enumerate}    
\usepackage{verbatim}        
\usepackage{floatflt}        
\usepackage{rotating}           
\usepackage{longtable}        
\usepackage{natbib}          
  \usepackage{url}        
   \bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{a}{ }{,}
   \RequirePackage{ifpdf}
   \ifpdf \PassOptionsToPackage{pdfa,a4paper=true,pagebackref=true}{hyperref} \fi
   \RequirePackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usepackage[final]{microtype}
   \usepackage{mathtools,stmaryrd}
   \usepackage{tabularx}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{pdflscape}
   \usepackage{bussproofs}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{alltt}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{afterpage}
   \usepackage{dirtytalk}
   \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.90}
   \def\mydoubleq#1{``#1''}
   \def\mysingleq#1{`#1'}

\begin{document}

\section{sect 1} ...

\section{sect 2} ...

\begin{example} ....example 1

\end{example}

\begin{example} Taking table .... example2

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I don't know why the output is with brackets as the following [image]

How I can hide these brackets? 
Thanks

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please provide a full but minimal example so we can se if we get the same result as you do. The information you provide should not just add random [] to the output, so we need a full (but minimal) document to test this

Comment: Please show the code that generates the output `Example 3.2.2 []`.

Comment: that is not a minimal example we can use, you are missing the rest of the preamble, including the document class. Please provide something compilable as is, that gives this issue.

Comment: adding some standard document class does not reproduce the problem

Comment: You are still not providing something we can copy and compile as is, there is not document class.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `theorem` package because there is already another package for theorems in the code. No necessary to have 3 package for theorems.

Also remove `thmtools` if you don't want warning in your document.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
%\usepackage{thmtools}
%\usepackage{theorem}    

\begin{document}

\section{sect 1} ...

\section{sect 2} ...

\begin{example} ....example 1

\end{example}

\begin{example} Taking table .... example2

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `thmtools` should be fine, but is clearly not used in this case.

Comment: @daleif With `thmtools` I get a warning `The remreset package is obsolete:(remreset) \@removefomresset is defined.` so I though better no use it if not necessary

Comment: That is just because thmtools has not been updated since the contents of the remreset package was included into the latex kernel.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for this information.